# how can I set focus to a textview and window in GTK

Tags: c#, gtk

I tried

```
textview.GrabFocus();
```

but it does nothing. Is there any way to do that? (Please try to answer this time instead of telling me to use google - I have tried and failed, thanks).

I also tried the same for a window:

```
            // searchbox is a GTK window, which was initialised on load of this form
            searchbox.Show();
            searchbox.GrabFocus();
            // this function will set focus to text box
            searchbox.setFocus();
```

the main window in this case open a new window and is supposed to make this new window focused, and certain text box in this window focused - it doesn't work though and I have no idea why, full source code:

the window I am opening: https://github.com/pidgeonproject/pidgeon/blob/gtk%23/Forms/ScriptEdit.cs

the window from which I am opening: https://github.com/pidgeonproject/pidgeon/blob/gtk%23/Forms/Main.cs#L520

Comment: Have you made it editable?  Also not sure what you mean by "text control in textview".

Comment: yes it is editable, I meant the control of "textview" itself as a part of window

Answer (score 1):

okay so given that this is probably very uncommon problem that was related to configuration of my application I don't expect anyone to solve it, however I found out what the problem was.

The window I created was of type

`window.Hint = Gtk.WindowTypeHint.Utility`

And for some reason unknown to me, it's not possible to set focus for this window. It may be even bug inside of GTK, but changing this to Normal did work.

Comment: Well this was in 2013, but I believe I did try, if it worked I probably wouldn't have asked here ;)